# Unexpected syntax error when Vue app deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js, webpack

I had a Vue app set up with Vue CLI webpack template, and I was trying to deploy it to Heroku with Node.js.

1. First I run `npm run build` (building with `webpack.prod` file), getting all file to be in `dist/`
2. Then I run `git push heroku master` to deploy it

When I open the web there is an error. I notice all `.js` files had changed to contain the same content of my `index.html`:

[image: chrome console]
[image: chrome sources]

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var app = express();

var staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.set('port',process.env.PORT||5000);

app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("App now running on port", app.get('port'));
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> First I run `npm run build`… Then I run `git push heroku master` to deploy it"

Unless you're not telling us something, `npm run build` does nothing useful here. `git push` operates on commits but your generated `dist/` files haven't been committed.

That's probably okay, though, since Heroku [can build your application itself](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process). Add a `postinstall` script to your `package.json` file to tell it how:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm run build"
}
```

This assumes that your build is actually generating valid output in `dist/`. If that's not happening there's a second problem to deal with.